# Importing pyodbc on OS X fails

Tags: python, osx-lion, pyodbc

I am trying to use pyodbc on OS X 10.7 and Python 2.7.
But the 'import pyodbc' statement causes the following error:

```
>>> import pyodbc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(./pyodbc.so, 2): Symbol not found: _GetPrivateProfileString
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have been looking on Google and tried to reinstall pyodbc by following different tutorials, without any luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please try the most recent version, [3.0.7](https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/list).